# asp.net c# label text not updating on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to set the label text of a specific label in my asp.net web application on page load. I have an external application which will request my web application (on button click) and passing a token in the requested URL to my web application. My c# code looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string token = Request.QueryString["token"];
        lblToken.Text = "Token: " + token;
    }
}
```

The event fires correctly and the token is also filled. If I debug the code it looks like this:

[image: token]

But on my web page it just says "Token:" without the token string.

Edit:

This is my code in the `Main.aspx` file:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblToken" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Edit 2:

The external application logs this when requesting my application:

```
09:57:28 Requesting web page : https://localhost:59917/Main.aspx?token=2gNWuAcDqkZ8N2mcKpZOubE9NfTtIjpssd7sSzkAB2MvJ1If0pbWWCZfIb4erPGo
```

**Edit 3 (Test):**

I added a button with a button click to test the label text update. So my test code looks like this:

```
string test = "foo";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblToken.Text = test;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test = "bar";
}
```

The label does not update as well and the string `test` always stays "foo", even in the debugger. Since I'm new to asp.net I don't know if this behaviour is correct and if this relates/help in any way for my problem?

Comment: Can you post your ASPX and the rest of the code in your code-behind ?

Comment: Are you sure there is token in your query string?

Comment: Could the rest of it not displaying because of css issues? What does inspecting element from the browser say ? Or maybe you override the label text in another part of your code without noticing.

Comment: @Seany84 I've added my .aspx code. I don't have any more .cs code in code behind.

Comment: @DávidFlorek Well the token in the external application log is exactly the same as the token in my asp.net web application and as you can see in the debugger the token string is filled. So I guess yes, or is there any other place where the token can be?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either ASPX or code-behind, as @AlkisGiamalis and Dávid have mentioned, it looks like something from outside of this page that is causing the issue.

Comment: @AlkisGiamalis I don't have any css code in my application and the code above is the only code I have in my application.

Comment: @Seany84 I don't have any other code (whether css nor anything else). The aspx and the cs is the only code I have.

Comment: Can you change the line that sets the label's text to: `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) { lblToken.Text = "Empty Token!"; } else {         lblToken.Text = "Token: " + token;
}`

Comment: @Seany84 It says "empty token". But if I go through the code step by step with the debugger the label text is correct and the else block is executed. It looks like it cannot display the label text correctly.

Comment: Can you show us how are you invoking this page from the external application?

Comment: @Boney the external application was written from a different company. I don't have the source code there. It simply has a button and when I click it the application will create a request on my web application. I've edited my question, see "Edit 2". This does the external application log when I hit the request button.

Comment: You have said - "external application which will send a token to my web application". Are they loading your web page by making a GET request ?

Comment: @Boney Yes, I'm sorry, this was badly described in my question, I'll edit this. Yes the application does a GET request to `https://localhost:59917/Main.aspx` adding a token argument. I have to get this token argument.

Comment: very weird. Try making this call through fiddler and see if you are getting the expected response.
`https://localhost:59917/Main.aspx?token=2gNWuAcDqkZ8N2mcKpZOubE9NfTtIjpssd7sSzkAB2MvJ1If0pbWWCZfIb4erPGo`

Comment: @Boney When I call the requested URL in browser it says `Token: 2gNWuAcDqkZ8N2mcKpZO‌​ubE9NfTtIjpssd7sSzkA‌​B2MvJ1If0pbWWCZfIb4e‌​rPGo`. So my label gets updated when I call the requested URL. It should also be updated when I've opened `/Main.aspx`. In the debugger it looks good, but not on the `/Main.aspx` web page.

Comment: @Therk do you have a valid SSL cert setup on your local machine? Is it possible to test if the external application can hit your application on `HTTP` and not `HTTPS` ?

Comment: @Seany84 Yes, I setup the SSL certificate & the https page using this article: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates. The external application only supports `HTTPS` requests. If I try to change the request URL to `HTTP` protocol it displays a message on startup that `HTTP` is not supported.

Comment: @Therk Do you have port `59917` mapped to `HTTPS` in your IIS ?

Comment: @Seany84 Yes, I followed the instructions in the article. I now created one new asp.net app, running on a different port and setup the IIS configuration again for the new page. So everything is completely new. But the problem is still the same.

Comment: Make sure https is using port 59917 and not 443. Can you try that please ?

Comment: @Therk: Since you are getting the correct response from the server in fiddler, issue should be something on the client side. Can you try disabling the javascript in browser or just check the source by right clicking 'View Page Source' in browser.

Comment: @Seany84 I already use https binding on port 59917.

Comment: @Boney I disabled javascript. No difference. The page source has nothing special I think. Some hidden inputs  called `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and of course my form. I already changed the method of my form to `GET`, without any difference on the page.

Comment: @Therk: I meant do you see the token value like in page source like you saw in fiddler response. ?

Comment: @Boney No, unfortunately not :/

Comment: @Boney It looks like the label does never update. I did now the following test: I added a string outside the `Page_Load()` event with the content "foo". Then I added a button with a click event. The click event updates the string to "bar". As soon as I click the button, the string changes to "bar" but then the `Page_Load()` event is fired again and the string is "foo" again. Since I'm new to asp.net I don't know if this is a normal behaviour. Maybe it's related somehow to my problem?

Comment: @Therk: Sorry i don't fully follow your comment. Where do you set the text  to the Label ? In general, for every button click, first the `Page_Load` event fires and then the `Btn_Click` event. So any value you set in the `Page_Load` event will be overwritten in `Btn_Click` event.

Comment: @Boney I only did this to test. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144949/discussion-between-boney-and-therk).